# Javascript Random Clickthrough

Tags: javascript, random

I am creating an image which, when you click on it, sends you to one of four links. I have managed to code this, but the problem I am having is that it is completely random (only part of the point). What I would like to be able to do is to randomise the first click through, and then if the user goes back to the image, only leave them with the remaining three destinations, and then obviously two and one at the end. This is to stop them theoretically ending up at the same link every single time and not being able to access the other three.

Does anybody know how I might be able to do this? The code I have currently is:

```
<img src="IMAGE" onclick="randomLink();">

<script type="text/javascript">
  var randomLink = function () {
    var links = ["LINK 1","LINK 2","LINK 3","LINK 4",];
    var max = (links.length)
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*max);
    var link = links[randomNumber];
    window.location = "http://" + link;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What should happen the fifth time?

Comment: Why the trailing comma in the array?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the selected entry from the `links` array (i.e. using `Array.splice`). Next time the user clicks the link, you would generate a random number between 0 and 2 only and so on.